# Python 3.x: parse ATOM XML and convert to dict

Tags: python, json, xml, python-3.x

I'm struggling to parse an ATOM XML file, coming from an API, to a common data structure, like `dict`, `Pandas dataframe` or `JSON`,

I understand XML files are more complex than JSON files, and hence there won't be a very simple, generic solution to this. I hope that given the fact that I'm dealing with an ATOM structure might help parsing the file to a more general data structure.

The structure of the XML data: http://opendata.cbs.nl/ODataFeed/OData/70266ned/TypedDataSet
And similar for JSON here: http://opendata.cbs.nl/ODataFeed/OData/70266ned/TypedDataSet

The reason I can't use the JSON file is that it is often not available.

I played around with libraries like `xml.etree`, `xmltodict`, `lxml`, `xmljson` and `feedparser`, but I keep getting errors.

For example, using `feedparser`:

```
r = requests.get('http://opendata.cbs.nl/ODataFeed/OData/70266ned/TypedDataSet')
tree = ElementTree.fromstring(r.content)
```

Yields the error

```
xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: not well-formated (invalid token): line 1, column 0
```

Help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you solved it yet but, have you tried using?:

```
tree = ElementTree.fromstring(r.text)
```

`r.content` returns the content in bytes (see: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#requests.Response)